# Group Policy Management Access Denied on Delegation Tab

Tags: permissions, active-directory, group-policy

I'm running a Windows Active Directory Domain using two 2016 DCs. Everything about the domain and my GPO policies are functioning correctly. However, when I open up Group Policy Management and then select a linked GPO in an OU and then select the Delegation tab I get a 'Access is Denied' modal dialog.  If I select a GPO in the 'Group Policy Objects' container then I immediately get an 'Access is Denied' modal dialog.

[image]
It doesn't seem to matter what group I am part of (Administrators, Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins) and I've reviewed the policies permissions in SYSVOL and nothing seems wrong to me. So far this is just a nuisance but I'm wondering what the cause is and how to fix it.

I also noticed a couple of other details:

1. The WMI Filtering portion on the Scope tab of the Policy details is missing.
2. There are no users listed in the Security Filtering portion of the Scope tab for the policy details.

I log into a member server or the domain controller then gpmc functions properly (no access denied message for delegation, WMI Filtering shows up, Security Filtering has its users populated)

I enabled group policy management logging via registry keys and compared the log output from a good system to a bad system. Its very clear that my workstation is getting an access denied, but there's no clear reason why that should be the case.

Bad:

```
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:087  [VERBOSE] CEffectivePermissionsTable::Load(): Loading from cn={xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=myname,DC=mydomain,DC=com.
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:106  [WARNING] CSecurityUtility::GetDSSecurityDescriptorDacl(): GetNamedSecurityInfo for LDAP://MyDC1.myname.mydomain.com/cn={xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=myname,DC=mydomain,DC=com failed with 0x80070005.
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:106  [WARNING] CGPOPermissionsTable::GetSecurityDescriptors(): GetDSSecurityDescriptorDacl failed with 0x80070005.
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:106  [WARNING] CEffectivePermissionsTable::Load(): GetSecurityDescriptors failed with 0x80070005.
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:106  [WARNING] CGPMSecurityInfo::Load(): Load failed with 0x80070005.
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:107  [VERBOSE] CGPMGPO::GetSecurityInfo(): Loading for GPO cn={xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=myname,DC=mydomain,DC=com
[127c.2f4] 11/07/2023 09:32:33:107  [WARNING] CGPMGPO::GetSecurityInfo(): Load failed with 0x80070005.
```

Good:

```
[192c.528] 11/07/2023 03:57:42:427  [VERBOSE] CEffectivePermissionsTable::Load(): Loading from cn={xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=myname,DC=mydomain,DC=com.
[192c.528] 11/07/2023 03:57:42:443  [VERBOSE] CEffectivePermissionsTable::GetOrAddEntry: Entry already found for S-1-5-11
[192c.528] 11/07/2023 03:57:42:443  [VERBOSE] CGPMSecurityInfo::Load(): Dumping permissions table.
[192c.528] 11/07/2023 03:57:42:443  [VERBOSE] ==========BEGIN EFFECTIVE PERMISSIONS LIST DUMP==========
...dumps ACLS.....
```

In seeing the access denied message in the logs, I used ldp.exe bound as my user on the workstation and it too is able to query and retrieve the ACLs without issue.

Additionally, Get-GPPermission from my workstation also returns an access denied but not on a Member Server or DC.

Comment: You may want to try running the command prompt as system, and run gpmc from there. `psexec -s -i cmd.exe`

Comment: Same issue if I run under SYSTEM. If it had fixed it I'd still be clueless as to where the permission Deny for this is happining.

Comment: Can you run icacls against the policy folder in the SYSVOL folder and view the permissions?

Comment: Yes. I've reviewed all the policy permissions in SYSVOL and they look fine. I'm able to add, edit, and remove GPOs without issue.

Comment: If the permissions for the SYSVOL folder are ok, I would check the permissions of the AD path in AD Users and Computers under System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by having 'Require Signing' enabled for LDAP on the domain controller (CIS L1) and not having a similar setting on our workspace clients. I think this is a fairly unusual situation.

Setting `Require Signing` on the DC requires

> Local Computer Policy-->Computer Configuration-->Policies-->Windows Settings-->Security Settings-->Local Policies-->Security Options: Domain controller: LDAP server signing requirements = `Require signing`

and the clients require

> Local Computer Policy-->Computer Configuration-->Policies-->Windows Settings-->Security Settings-->Local Policies-->Security Options: Network security: LDAP client signing requirements Properties = `Require signing`

I'm not sure why GPMC doesn't try LDAPS by default but judging by the logs and this issue it does not. Also, I was able to use ldp.exe to query the security descriptors but I was using LDAPS for that. I changed the `Connection` properties to use port 389 and unchecked SSL and after doing that I was unable to view the DACLs for the policies and this error was returned

```
-----------
Error: Security: No Such Attribute. <16>
Server error: <empty>
-----------
```